# sql compare two dates, when working with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem. Using C#, I retrieve a date from SQL Server.
I then use that same date to try to retrieve the same row it was in.

Unfortunately that didn't work. The reason is that SQL Server stores dates with millisecond precision, while C# `DateTime` only stores dates with second precision. The millisecond part was preventing me from selecting the row.

How do we deal with this minute discrepancy?

Comment: No, [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) includes milliseconds, invalidating the need for your answer. You should put your SQL queries in your question, along with the C# code where you build up the SelectCommand. Then we can probably figure out why you think it lacks milliseconds. DateTime is actually accurate to the "tick", and there are 10000 ticks in a millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

The problem we are trying to solve is, how do we select rows, when a loss of precision is preventing us from selecting the correct row?

The answer I found was to use the SQL function DATEDIFF (datepart, startdate, enddate).

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE DATEDIFF (second, SellByDate, SellByDate) = 0
```

This guarantees we select the correct row, since:

1. The dates are the same, with only a discrepancy of less than a second.
2. DATEDIFF will reduce that difference to 0